# how to plot dotted / dashed lines using rgl

Tags: r, rgl

I'm trying to plot some 3d shapes using rgl, but I want to connect my points using dashed/dotted lines. How can I do that? Currently I have

```
require(rgl)

p1 <- c(0,0,0)
p2 <- c(1,0,0)
p3 <- c(1,1,0)
p4 <- c(0,1,0)
p5 <- c(0.5,0.5,0.5)

mat <- cbind(p1,p2,p3,p4,p1,p5,p2,p5,p3,p5,p4)
x <- as.numeric(mat[1,])
y <- as.numeric(mat[2,])
z <- as.numeric(mat[3,])

plot3d(x,y,z,type="l",lwd=2,lty=3,box=FALSE,axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="",zlab="")
```

So `lwd` works but `lty` doesn't. I've tried `lty="dashed"` as well, but to no avail.

I essentially want to plot 3d shapes that I can

1. Easily rotate around / zoom (like what rgl gives)
2. Export to a vector graphics format (like rgl.postscript)
3. Specify line type and color

If there is another package that can achieve that, please share too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best you can do with the rgl package is vertices as dots:

```
vertices <- c(t(cbind(x,y,z,1)))
indices <- seq_along(x)
dot3d( qmesh3d(vertices,indices) )
```

Comment: Hi when I run the code above with my `x,y,z` paramters, I got a warning message: `Warning message: In matrix(indices, nrow = 4) : data length [11] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [4]`, and the 5 points are plotted as 5 dots. The dots are not joined at all. Is that the expected output?

Comment: the above fives me the following:  data length [11] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [4] and no figure!